# How to create text index in mongoid 5?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid5

I have this in my model

`index({company_name: 1, first_name: 1, last_name: 1 })`

`Model.text_search 'something'`

gives this error

`Mongo::Error::OperationFailure: text index required for $text query`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution

`index({company_name: 'text', first_name: 'text', last_name: 'text' })`

You just have to pass 'text' instead of 1.